# Why is mocked response unable to be decoded?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to test an api call with mocked data, but I get the following error. The mocked response that i declared should be decoded so that the handler can pass the data correctly to the caller, but it's not allowing me to because the mocked response should  be of type Data. I'm not sure how to get my mocked response to be of type Data without it giving me more errors.

[image]

```
 let mockCommentsResponse: [[String: Any]] = [
        [
          "requestCommentId": 22377,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "EVIQ",
          "requestComment": "Delivery Date added by EVIQ",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 13:00:08",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 13:00:08",
          "commentType": "System"
        ],
        [
          "requestCommentId": 22372,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "Customer",
          "requestComment": "Form Submitted by Customer",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:32:19",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:32:19",
          "commentType": "System"
        ],
        [
          "requestCommentId": 22371,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "Customer",
          "requestComment": "Awaiting Form Completion",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:31:17",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:31:17",
          "commentType": "System"
        ],
        [
          "requestCommentId": 22370,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "usa_dealer",
          "requestComment": "Sent VIN to Maritz",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:29:34",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:29:34",
          "commentType": "System"
        ]
    ]

func getComments(requestId:String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[Comment], Error>) -> Void) {
        
        if shouldReturnError {
            completionHandler(.failure(MockServiceError.getComments))
        } else {
            let decoded = try self.decoder.decode([Comment].self, from: mockCommentsResponse)
           
            completionHandler(.success(decoded))
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.decode` expects `Data` as its second parameter. You're providing `[String:Any]`.

One option would be to convert your mocked structure to valid JSON and use data(using: .utf8)`:

```
let mockCommentsResponse = """
[
        {
          "requestCommentId": 22377,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "EVIQ",
          "requestComment": "Delivery Date added by EVIQ",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 13:00:08",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 13:00:08",
          "commentType": "System"
        },
        {
          "requestCommentId": 22372,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "Customer",
          "requestComment": "Form Submitted by Customer",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:32:19",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:32:19",
          "commentType": "System"
        },
        {
          "requestCommentId": 22371,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "Customer",
          "requestComment": "Awaiting Form Completion",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:31:17",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:31:17",
          "commentType": "System"
        },
        {
          "requestCommentId": 22370,
          "installRequestId": 27236,
          "enteredByValue": "usa_dealer",
          "requestComment": "Sent VIN to Maritz",
          "creationTs": "2021-09-17 12:29:34",
          "modificationTs": "2021-09-17 12:29:34",
          "commentType": "System"
        }
    ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

Another option would be to define your `mockCommentsResponse` as an actual array of `Comment` and then encode them to JSON/Data using `JSONEncoder` and then decode them again. But, that probably raises questions about *what* you're actually testing in that case.

Comment: Did this answer your question?